# Date d = new Date(); returns phone date if backdated not actual date

Tags: android

I am trying to get actual date even if phone (Android) is backdated. I used below lines of code:

```java
SimpeDateFormat dateformatter = new SimpeDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date today = dateformatter.parse(dateformatter.format(new Date()));
```

When I run app on my phone with backdated date, it prints only phone date, not actual date. I need to get current date not phone date, please help me. Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Make a Web service request of your server to give you the current date/time. Use that to calculate the difference between the current date/time and the phone date/time, so you can avoid having to keep calling the Web server to get the date/time. Or, find an SNTP client library and use that.

Comment: Try this Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287994/check-the-phone-clock-is-correct

Comment: I dont want use network provider date.

Comment: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime()); is returning backdated date only not actual date.

Comment: Is there any way to make App expire on specific date(say 31 March 2017). App should not work even if the phone date is backdated. (Note: Android phone can be back dated if Automatic date and time is unchecked.)

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't get backdated date.

You can use `new Date()` only to get the current time on the phone.
You can create a Web service request of your server to give you the current date/time.

Comment: Is there any way to make App expire on specific date(say 31 March 2017). App should not work even if the phone date is backdated. (Note: Android phone can be back dated if Automatic date and time is unchecked.)